# Adjust typeblocksize in light of paper size

Tags: margins, memoir, calculations

I'm trying to figure out how to adjust the typeblocksize in memoir in light of the ratio of `\paperheight` to `\paperwidth`.

Right now, I have

```
\settypeblocksize{*}{\lxvchars}{1.414}
```

to adjust the `\textheight` to 1.414 time the value of `\lxvchars` (itself calculated based on font and pointsize). This works fine for metric paper whose height is sqrt( 2 ) times the width.

I'd like to replace this with a variable expression based on the paper size selected in the documentclass. I.e. something like

```
\settypeblocksize{*}{\lxvchars}{\paperheight / \paperwidth}
```

but I can't figure out how to replace the scalar 1.414 with an expression (either inline or else computed elsewhere.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `calc` package's `\ratio` command may be of some help:

```
\documentclass[10pt,crownvopaper,landscape]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\settypeblocksize{\lxvchars*\ratio{\paperheight}{\paperwidth}}{\lxvchars}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Note that `memoir` doesn't seem to like using `\ratio` as the third parameter.

By the way, I tend to resist the temptation to believe that making the typeblock the same shape (ratio) as the page gives one a good layout *automatically*... :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had looked at calc but had trouble making sense of the instructions. And I agree with your reservation; but I want to try it and see....